# C Coding: Am I printing this array from a node incorrectly?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

Im making a linked list with a given input of int value, char string, and an array. For some reason though despite the adress for the array being the same when printed from the print function the values in the array have changed, but when printed straight from the function i am given the proper values etc. The first set of code is my main and the following one is the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "a03input.h"

// Define the struct
struct stNode {

    double avg;
    char* name;
    int* prodID;
    struct stNode *next;

};//stNode

typedef struct stNode Node;

// Implement the following function
void  createList(Node **head, Node **tail){

    Node* oTmp;
    Node* tmp;
    int index = 0;
    int shiftTo;

    for(int i = 0;i < INPUTSIZE; i++){

        oTmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        oTmp -> avg = a03input_avg[i];
        oTmp -> name = a03input_name[i];
        int arr[a03input_num[i]];
        oTmp -> prodID= arr;
        shiftTo = index;

            for(int j = 0; j < a03input_num[i]; j++){

                arr[j]=a03input_prodIDs[shiftTo];
                shiftTo++;

        }

        index = index+a03input_num[i];
        oTmp -> next = NULL;

        if( *head == NULL){

            *head  = oTmp;
                }

                else{
                    tmp = *head;
                    while(tmp -> next != NULL){
                    tmp = tmp -> next;
            }

            tmp -> next = oTmp;
        }
    }
} // createList

// Implement the following function
void printList(Node *head){

    Node *cur;
    cur = head;
    int i = 0;

    while(cur != NULL){

        printf("%-12s", cur -> name);
        printf("%.2f ", cur -> avg);
        printf("[ ");
            for(int j = 0;j < a03input_num[i]; j++){

                printf(" %d", (cur -> prodID)[j]);

        }

        printf("] \n");
        cur = cur -> next;
        i++;

    }
} // printList

// Implement the following function
void freeList(Node **head, Node **tail) {

    Node *cur = *head;

        while(cur != NULL){

        free(cur);
        cur = cur -> next;

    }

} // freeList


// DO NOT change the main()
int main() {
    Node        *head = NULL;
    Node        *tail = NULL;

    createList(&head, &tail);
    printList(head);
    freeList(&head, &tail);

    return 0;
}
```

```
#ifndef A03INPUT_H
#define A03INPUT_H

#define INPUTSIZE   15    
double a03input_avg[INPUTSIZE] = {  99.12,
                                    48,
                                    13,
                                    88.67,
                                    19,
                                    43,
                                    99.34,
                                    21.8,
                                    5.12,
                                    88.01,
                                    0,
                                    27.23,
                                    98.45,
                                    65.12,
                                    0.0
                                };

char *a03input_name[INPUTSIZE] = {  "Alfred",
                                    "Ben",
                                    "Catherine",
                                    "Dana",
                                    "Ether",
                                    "Frank",
                                    "Gab",
                                    "Harry",
                                    "Ian",
                                    "Johnny",
                                    "Kerry",
                                    "Leo",
                                    "Mike",
                                    "Nathan",
                                    "Olivia"
                                 };

int a03input_num[INPUTSIZE] = {     3,
                                    2,
                                    1,
                                    2,
                                    5,
                                    1,
                                    4,
                                    5,
                                    2,
                                    4,
                                    8,
                                    2,
                                    1,
                                    6,
                                    0
                                };

int a03input_prodIDs[] = { 1012, 1031, 1001, 1002, 1005, 1006, 1008, 9012, 9016, 10024, 
                           7085, 7012, 7016, 7080, 7068, 7001, 7007, 7021, 7018, 7088,
                           3085, 3012, 3016, 3080, 3068, 3001, 3007, 3021, 3018, 3088,
                           8085, 8012, 8016, 8080, 8068, 8001, 8007, 8021, 8018, 8088,
                           6085, 6012, 6016, 6080, 6068, 6001, 6007, 6021, 6018, 7088
                         };
#endif
```

```
The following is the output generated from the main code:

Alfred      99.12 [  1 0 1243544112]
Ben         48.00 [  1 0]
Catherine   13.00 [  1]
Dana        88.67 [  1 0]
Ether       19.00 [  8 0 1243544112 32766 1]
Frank       43.00 [  1]
Gab         99.34 [  1 0 1243544112 32766]
Harry       21.80 [  8 0 1243544112 32766 1]
Ian         5.12 [  1 0]
Johnny      88.01 [  1 0 1243544112 32766]
Kerry       0.00 [  8 0 1243544112 32766 1 0 1243544112 32766]
Leo         27.23 [  1 0]
Mike        98.45 [  1]
Nathan      65.12 [  8 0 1243544112 32766 1 0]
Olivia      0.00 [ ]

And this is the expected output:

Alfred     99.12 -> [ 1012 1031 1001 ]
Ben        48.00 -> [ 1002 1005 ]
Catherine  13.00 -> [ 1006 ]
Dana       88.67 -> [ 1008 9012 ]
Ether      19.00 -> [ 9016 10024 7085 7012 7016 ]
Frank      43.00 -> [ 7080 ]
Gab        99.34 -> [ 7068 7001 7007 7021 ]
Harry      21.80 -> [ 7018 7088 3085 3012 3016 ]
Ian         5.12 -> [ 3080 3068 ]
Johnny     88.01 -> [ 3001 3007 3021 3018 ]
Kerry       0.00 -> [ 3088 8085 8012 8016 8080 8068 8001 8007 ]
Leo        27.23 -> [ 8021 8018 ]
Mike       98.45 -> [ 8088 ]
Nathan     65.12 -> [ 6085 6012 6016 6080 6068 6001 ]
Olivia      0.00 -> [ ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
int arr[a03input_num[i]];
oTmp -> prodID= arr;
```

The array `arr` is ***local*** inside the `createList` function. Once the function returns the life-time of `arr` ends and it ceases to exist, leaving any pointer to it invalid.

You need to allocate it dynamically for each node.